# Rails - trouble using has_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through, has-many

I apologize if this is a big question. I used to be good at rails but it has been a long time.

I am working a rails project and am having trouble with the has_many relation.

I have the following tables:

```
User
SchoolClass
Question
UserClassQuestion
```

Inside the models i have:

```
user.rb
   has_many :questions, :through => :user_class_questions
   has_many :user_class_questions

school_class.rb
   has_many :questions, :through => :user_class_questions
   has_many :user_class_questions

question.rb
   belongs_to :schoolclass
   belongs_to :user

user_class_question.rb
   belongs_to :question
```

So, what I want is to on a users home page, display let them view the questions they have asked with `current_user.questions`. This works.

But on the `SchoolClass` show page, if i say `@school_class.questions`, i get the following error:

```
!!<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such colum:
 user_class_questions.school_class_id: SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions" 
INNER JOIN "user_class_questions" ON "questions"."id" = 
"user_class_questions"."question_id" WHERE 
"user_class_questions"."school_class_id" = ?>
```

`@school_class` is an object set by the params

```
def set_school_class
   @school_class = SchoolClass.find(params[:id])
end
```

The columns in `UserClassQuestion` table are:

```
{ user_id: , schoolclass_id: , question_id }
```

So, do I have something set up wrong?

Comment: have you tried `has_and_belongs_to_many` ?

Comment: Where are you proposing using that? A `user has_many questions` and a `question belongs_to user`. I want that same relationship to work for the `SchoolClass` table. 
It looks like the relationship is working, but the database command is saying it doesnt know what `school_class_id` to search for. Like its not getting the id from the `@school_class`

Comment: hmm I thought of writing `user.rb : has_and_belongs_to_many :schoolclasses, schoolclass.rb: has_and_belongs_to_many :users`

Comment: but I think you need the `question` model

Comment: in that case I suggest you remove user_class_question.rb and replace `:through => :user_class_questions` with simply `:through => :questions`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're experiencing is most likely due to the variation in your column name. In Rails, `school_class_id` is not the same as `schoolclass_id`. I think a quick way to work around, is to specify the `primary_key/foreign_key` in your belongs_to option.

A more lasting solution is to run a migration to rename your column to `school_class_id` rather than `schoolclass_id`.

Let me know if I was able to help.

**UPDATE**

if the `belongs_to :school_class` is defined on `question`, then you have access to question.school_class and your school_class model should just have has_many :questions, no need of running to a join table to do that as that would confuse rails a bit. If however you don't want it this way you could comment out the `belongs_to :school_class` assoication and instead have a `has_many :user_class_questions` on `question`

```
class User
   has_many :questions, through: :user_class_questions
   has_many :user_class_questions
end

class SchoolClass
   has_many :questions, through: :user_class_questions
   has_many :user_class_questions
end

class Question
   #belongs_to :school_class
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :user_class_questions
end

class UserClassQuestion
   belongs_to :question
   belongs_to :school_class
   belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: I just tried that but it had no help. 

I had thought about the column name and I changed it but it leads to issues when seeding the database.

If i understand correctly, `schoolclass_id` means, table `SchoolClass` index = `_id`

If i said `school_class_id` it would mean a different table no?

Comment: Sorry for the previous `belongs_to` association. I've edited to reflect the best approach. No, schoolclass_id means Schoolclass index = `_id`, while school_class_id means SchoolClass index = `_id`

Comment: I just dont understand where rails is getting `school_class_id` from. 

If all of my relations and models are set properly, then `@school_class.questions` should be using the `user_class_question` table to find the questions just like it does for `current_user.questions`

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around the associations you've set up but I've updated the answer accordingly with what I'm thinking

Comment: It has been a while since I made an in depth rails project, so i probably set them up wrong. I am actually starting fresh now, and will probably post all my associations to get a little verification from people if possible to see if im missing something important this time. .

Answer (score 0):

Your Data model needs a bit of a change, your `UserClassQuestion` is a join model and it should have data about the User, SchoolClass, and Question. So the relationship should be something like

`UserClassQuestion`
`rails g model UserClassQuestion user:references school_class:references question:references`

```
class UserClassQuestion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :school_class
  belongs_to :question
end
```

`school_class.rb`

```
class SchoolClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_class_questions
  has_many :questions, through: :user_class_questions
end
```

`user.rb`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_class_questions
  has_many :questions, through: :user_class_questions
end
```

And then you can do `user.questions` and `school_class.questions`

Also try not to use has_many_and_belongs_to association, I feel it is a bad idea, it creates a table without a primary id, and later on if you want to do something else with this join table, then this will come and bite you. has_many, through is a bit extra step but it is worth it.

Comment: I have since changed that and have the models exactly as you have written them.

I believe my issue is as the other answer said and is related to the column names and it looking for `school_class_id` instead of `schoolclass_id`